# Object not found! Error 404 localhost with XAMPP

Tags: php, url, xampp, localhost, http-status-code-404

I am experiencing difficulties in accessing files on my local Desktop.

Specifically, when I try to access a file with http://localhost/oliviahtml/log-in.php, the resulting error page is displayed:

[404 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBYOu.png)

However, after inspecting element, my page is recognized but the contents themselves are not being displayed.

[Inspect Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQRT9.png)

How can I display this php page on Chrome?  I am trying to run the program with XAMPP 5.6.32.0 for the php features

Comment: The second picture doesn't prove that your page is recognized. Please check whether the directory is correctly set in httpd.conf and whether log-in.php is there.

Comment: @Phil I just checked. The directory is correctly set

Comment: If you didn't use some frameworks(which will handle your `get` request by route), I am afraid you have to put the php files into the `htdocs` folder or other folder you set in `httpd.conf`. Otherwise you may not browse it via localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Put your php files inside C:\xampp\htdocs then agaain try to run  http://localhost/oliviahtml/log-in.php . it would work.

Comment: I'm trying to reset my directory to avoid moving my php files to htdocs

Comment: Let me know what you trying to do. On local system you must have php files inside htdocs directory.